# mySQL UPDATE with WHERE

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am trying to update p.product_status to 0 when two criteria are met.

```
UPDATE product p JOIN product_to_store p2s ON p.product_id = p2s.product_id
SET p.status=0 
WHERE p.quantity=0 AND p2s.store_id=2
```

If the p.product_id is in p2s and assigned to to p2s.store_id 2 it should not update p.status to 0.

```
product_id | store_id
         1 |        0
         1 |        2
         2 |        0
         3 |        0
         4 |        2
```

Let's say I have the above data in product_to_store.
Product Quantity (p.quantity=0) for all.

**Alt 1.** Product_id=1 and 4: The SQL should NOT update p.status=0 as product_id 1 also is assigned to both store_id 0 and 2.

**Alt 2.** Product_id=2 and 3: The SQL should update p.status=0 as product_id 2 is only assigned to store_id 0 (and not 2).

Comment: Please include sample data and desired result. It's kind of hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi, thx. I have updated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a JOIN, this should give the desired result:

```
UPDATE product p 
SET p.status=0
WHERE p.quantity=0
AND p.product_id IN (
  SELECT ps2.product_id
  FROM product_to_store p2s
  WHERE p2s.store_id=2
)
```

Although this may not be the most efficient solution depending on the number of records in each table, matching the predicates and represented in indexes.

**update**

To accomodate the redefined question:

```
UPDATE product p 
SET p.status=0
WHERE p.quantity=0
AND p.product_id IN (
  SELECT ps2.product_id
  FROM product_to_store p2s_r
  LEFT JOIN product_to_store p2s_2
  ON p2s_r.product_id=p2s_2.product_id
  AND p2s_2.store_id=2
  WHERE p2s_r.store_id<>2
  AND p2s_r.product_id IS NOT NULL
  AND p2s_2.product_id IS NULL
)
```

Comment: This is actually the same as a join and you haven't understood the requirements.

Comment: No, its not the same thing as a join, it just gives a similar result. Could you enlighten me as to what part of the requirements I don't understand?

Comment: It gives the **same** result as a join. To enlighten you: "Alt 1. Product_id=1 and 4: The SQL should NOT update p.status=0 as product_id 1 also is assigned **to both store_id 0 and 2.**"

Comment: @fancypants: No. Consider the case where there is more than one matched row in product_to_store table with a particular product_id. A JOIN will return 2 rows in the output while IN (...) will only return a single row. My answer was correct prior to the revision.

Comment: I get an error: Unknown column 'p2s.product_id' in 'field list'

Comment: @Hans: whoops, yes I used the wrong alias there. Should be p2s_r

Answer (score 2):

This query only updates products which are assigned to either store 0 or store 2.

```
UPDATE product p
JOIN (
  SELECT product_id 
  FROM product_to_store p2s
  WHERE store_id IN (0, 2) /*not clear, if this is a requirement*/
  GROUP BY product_id 
  HAVING SUM(store_id IN (0, 2)) < 2 OR COUNT(*) = 1
) p2s USING (product_id)
SET p.status = 0
WHERE p.quantity = 0;
```

The `store_id IN (0, 2)` in the `SUM()` function returns true or false, 1 or 0. Therefore we check if the number of rows where this statement is true is lower than 2. So it's either in this store or the other, not in both.

Comment: This worked when the product_id is stored for both store_id 0 and 2 in product_to_store ps2. But not if it is only in one (i.e. 2).

Comment: @HansLernestål Fixed that. Please try again.

Comment: Now it leaves product 1 (correct) and updates product 2, 3 and 4. It should not update product 4 (see list above).

Comment: Well, but product 4 is only assigned to store_id 2 according to your sample data.